# The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service terminated unexpectedly. Event ID: 7034

Tags: sql-server-2016, windows-server

## Unable to find the cause why the SQL Server Service was Terminated Unexpectedly? (Event ID: 7034)

I looked into the SQL Server Error Logs but could find the reason about why the SQL Server service was terminated.

**So check the windows event Viewer and I found the following error msg:**

**Event Message :** The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service terminated unexpectedly. It has done this 1 time(s).

**Error Event Id :** 7034

Since last night my SQL server service is terminating with the this error.

This service terminates and restarts automatically and sometimes doesn't restart we have to manually start it again.

**Version Details:**
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64) Standard Edition (64-bit)

**OS:** Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hyper-visor)

Comment: Do you see anything in your SQL Server error log and the windows event log (app, system, security) in the same time period? The generic 7034 is a symptom. Some thing happened prior to that resulting in SQL Server shutting down.

Comment: Yes, I did all those error logs but prior to this error:7034, I could not find any other issue.

I also check the SQL Server Error logs : but nothing was there that could help me.

Comment: @Kundan Dasange,Could you update the error log message of Event ID 7034.

Comment: Is there any Service Pack or Cumulative Update you’re planning to move to anytime soon?

Comment: Is that machine a virtual one? I've a similar problem currently and it really smells a lot of host memory issues (over-committing).

Comment: Yes; it's a virtual machine on AWS.

Answer (score -1):

> Error Event Id : 7034

Service Control Manager (SCM) stops services and driver services. It also reports when services terminate unexpectedly or fail to restart after it takes corrective action.

**How to Resolve**

```
Change the recovery actions
```

To resolve this issue, change the recovery actions that the `Service Control Manager (SCM)` will take when a service fails.
To perform this procedure, you must have membership in Administrators, or you must have been delegated the appropriate authority.

To change the recovery actions for a service:

1. Open the Services snap-in by clicking the Start button, Control
   Panel, and Administrative Tools, then double-clicking Services.
   Note: For Windows Vista, use the Classic View display option in
   Control Panel to see the Administration Tools.
2. In the details pane of the Services snap-in, right-click on the name
       of the service you want to stop and select Properties.
3. Click the Recovery tab and specify the recovery actions for the
       service (for example, restart the service or the computer, take no
       action, or run a program).

For your further ref [Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756320(v=ws.10).aspx) and [Here](http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/e6dd0872-d396-4245-8026-279fee5a83f3?category=sqlservermigration)

Comment: I won't do this until the root cause is identified. Even if it successfully restarts the service, you have no idea when it will strike again and what the impact might be (e.g. security, data integrity, nothing...).